# How is the dark mode on mobile targeted using media queries?

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, darkmode

### Desktop

If I use CSS:

```
    .header {
        background-image: url('https://www.example.com/img/header.png');
    }
    @media screen and (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
        .header {
            background-image: url('https://www.example.com/img/header_dark.png');
        }
    }
```

then the `https://www.example.com/img/header_dark.png` is used in desktop mail clients that are using dark modes, such as Office 365 macOS and macOS Ventura Mail, which is correct behaviour.

### Mobile

If I use:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .header {
    height: 150px;
    background-image: url('https://www.example.com/service_desk/header_mobile.png');
  }
}     
@media screen and (prefers-color-scheme: dark) and (max-width: 400px) {
  .header {
    height: 150px;
    background-image: url('https://www.example.com/service_desk/header_mobile_dark.png');
  }
}
```

then in all mobile clients using light mode and dark mode the `.header` has a background of `https://www.example.com/service_desk/header_mobile.png`, i.e. dark mode mobile email clients do not use `https://www.example.com/service_desk/header_mobile_dark.png`.

**How is the dark mode on mobile targeted using media queries?**

### Edit

If I use CSS:

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 780px) {
        .header {
            height: 150px;
            background-image: url('https://images.mandoemedia.com/service_desk/header_mobile.jpg');
        }
        [prefers-color-scheme="dark"] .header {
            height: 150px;
            background-image: url('https://images.mandoemedia.com/service_desk/header_mobile.png');
        }
    }
```

then the default image with white background `https://images.mandoemedia.com/service_desk/header_mobile.jpg` is used for all mobile dark mode email clients, instead of the image specified for dark mode `https://images.mandoemedia.com/service_desk/header_mobile.png`.

Comment: What email clients are you targeting? Some significant ones don't deal with media fully (or at all in some cases). When  you tested on desktop what OS were you using? See https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=%40media

Comment: @AHaworth, iPhone Gmail, iPhone Outlook, Android Gmail, Android Outlook. The first 3 don't work with `@media screen and (prefers-color-scheme: dark) and (max-width: 768px) {...` or `@media screen and (prefers-color-scheme: dark) and (max-width: 400px) {...`, I don't have a test for Android Outlook yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think the below answer is suitable for you.

if `prefers-color-scheme: dark` this is the attribute and value in your root tag

you can write CSS like this

```
[prefers-color-scheme="dark"] .header {
  height: 150px;
  background-image: url('https://www.example.com/service_desk/header_mobile_dark.png');
}
```

let me know if this does not satisfy you.

**Edited Answer**

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
      .header {
        height: 150px;
        background-image: url('https://www.example.com/service_desk/header_mobile.png');
      }
      [prefers-color-scheme="dark"] .header {
        height: 150px;
        background-image: url('https://www.example.com/service_desk/header_mobile_dark.png');
    }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-1rkieo?file=index.html,styles.css,script.js

Comment: Check the question please, I need to target mobile, that code has nothing to target mobile.

Comment: @Steve yes, you must write inside  "@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {}" this block

Comment: Thanks for that, I've made that change, but the default image is being used still. See the Edit to the question.

Comment: I think your image is repeated. so, try this on top of CSS .header {background-repeat: no-repeat;} If still you are facing any issues this is my Gmail id "logeshsankar.dev@gmail.com". You can arrange a small meeting after 9.30 PM IST.